# Bootstrap Dynamic Navbar won't resize for mobile since I included a logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a logo in the navbar of my website. This works great on larger screens but on smaller screens the navbar breaks

Without the logo:
[Click Here](http://www.newbrightonweatherstation.co.uk/theteam.html)
With the logo and resize issues:
[Click Here](http://www.newbrightonweatherstation.co.uk/theteam1.html)

I am guessing I can change the logo image to be responsive/disappear in the custom css for the page but not sure how to.
any help appreciated!

Comment: add img-responsive class to your image

Comment: @AbieGiordano hey i tried that still won't resize the navbar correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your logo to be smaller on smaller screens, so it is not bigger than the viewport, you should set a `max-width`-value in your CSS as you did it with your other pictures.

You can do this either by adding `max-width:100%` or adding your `.img-responsive`-class (which you used for the other pics) to the logo-tag.